# How to create a table with clickable hyperlink in pandas & Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-styles

`print('http://google.com')` outputs a clickable url.

How do I get clickable URLs for `pd.DataFrame(['http://google.com', 'http://duckduckgo.com'])` ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try using [`pd.DataFrame.style.format`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Finer-Control:-Display-Values) for this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['http://google.com', 'http://duckduckgo.com'])

def make_clickable(val):
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(val,val)

df.style.format(make_clickable)
```

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: you could use `'<a href="{0}">{0}</a>'.format(val)`

Comment: on a sidenote: first add the column via `apply..` then just `df.style` suffices

Comment: or Python3 you could use `f"<a href="{val}">{val}</a>"`

Comment: This looks great. As an addendum, how might I create a clickable link that executes an underlying function that I define elsewhere?

Answer (score 82):

If you want to apply URL formatting only to a single column, you can use:

```
data = [dict(name='Google', url='http://www.google.com'),
        dict(name='Stackoverflow', url='http://stackoverflow.com')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def make_clickable(val):
    # target _blank to open new window
    return '<a target="_blank" href="{}">{}</a>'.format(val, val)

df.style.format({'url': make_clickable})
```

(PS: Unfortunately, I didn't have enough reputation to post this as a comment to @Abdou's post)

Comment: How do I make the "name" clickable and hide the url?

Comment: @shantanuo Something like this: `df['nameurl'] = df['name'] + '#' + df['url']`, `def make_clickable_both(val): name, url = val.split('#'), return f'<a href="{url}">{name}</a>'`, `df.style.format({'nameurl': make_clickable_both})`

Comment: Great stuff! Question: is it possible then to delete the 'name'  and 'url' columns from df or can we create a new pandas data frame with only the 'nameurl' column?

Comment: @Alan : yes, only the nameurl column is needed. So you can e.g. use `new_df = df[['nameurl']]` to create a dataframe with only the `nameurl` column.

Comment: @ dloeckx Thanks!

Comment: @dloeckx .. If we have multiple columns in a dataframe , how to display complete dataframe in a web page (or html table to get displayed in hyper link)

Comment: @Ravi Take a look at `pandas.DataFrame.to_html()`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903773/pandas-dataframe-to-html-formatting-the-values-to-display-centered .

Comment: @dloeckx .. Thanks for the reply.. I am trying to display the html table in an url. I want to create a url and display this html data in that url , can you please help me if there is any link i can refer and try

Comment: @Ravi To be able to generate a URL and display this HTML data in that URL is beyond the reach of Pandas afaik. You can take a look at [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/) to setup a web server, or save the file to a directory that is served to the web. Note that if you would like to make the link public, you might open a lot of security holes!

Answer (score 10):

I found this at [How to Create a Clickable Link(s) in Pandas DataFrame and JupyterLab](https://datascientyst.com/create-clickable-link-pandas-dataframe-jupyterlab/) which solved my problem:

```py
HTML(df.to_html(render_links=True, escape=False))
```

Comment: In my case (JupyterNotebook) it requires `from IPython.display import HTML`

Answer (score 8):

@shantanuo  : not enough reputation to comment.
How about the following?

```
def make_clickable(url, name):
    return '<a href="{}" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">{}</a>'.format(url,name)

df['name'] = df.apply(lambda x: make_clickable(x['url'], x['name']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
import pandas as pd

# create a table with a url column
df = pd.DataFrame({"url": ["http://google.com", "http://duckduckgo.com"]})

# create the column clickable_url based on the url column
df["clickable_url"] = df.apply(lambda row: "<a href='{}' target='_blank'>{}</a>".format(row.url, row.url.split("/")[2]), axis=1)

# display the table as HTML. Note, only the clickable_url is being selected here
display(HTML(df[["clickable_url"]].to_html(escape=False)))
```