# Pandas DataFrame to HTML: Formatting the values to display centered

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have a `pandas` `DataFrame` and am using the `DataFrame.to_html` method to generate a table I can send within an HTML email message. I simply want the values in certain columns to be centered, but would also like to know in general how to apply formatting to the table. I have tried applying the documentation found [HERE](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) as well as using `df.style` before using `to_html` like so:

```
df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align':'center'})
```

But i am still getting all of my values left-aligned (other than the headers, which are centered).

What is the correct way to center all (or a subset) of my column values, and what are the other options available for formatting? (e.g. bolding text, changing background or border colors, etc.)

Further, at what stage should this formatting be applied? Within the `to_html` method or prior to it as I tried with `df.style`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest using the **formatters** within the `to_html` function, description of the parameter:

> **formatters** : list or dict of one-parameter functions, optional formatter functions to apply to columns’ elements by position or name,
>   default None. The result of each function must be a unicode string.
>   List must be of length equal to the number of columns.

Example if you want to make all your `Name` column bold:

```
df.to_html(formatters={'Name': lambda x: '<b>' + x + '</b>'})
```

Let me know whether it works!

Comment: This makes sense to me. Can you include an example where you use `formatters` to center all cell values (all columns)?

Comment: @RichardGolz If it's only for the purpose of centering the cells, I would probably just modify the string you get after using `df.to_html` by adding `align='center'` within the `<table>` tag so it becomes `<table align='center'>`, that to me is more straight forward than centering each column.

Comment: something like `html[:6] + ' align="center"' + html[6:]`

Comment: I now have `<table align="center" border="1" class="dataframe">` but it still appears to be left-aligned. Sigh. Below that I do see `<thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">` - wonder if that has anything to do with it (although my data is appearing left aligned)

Comment: Does `html.replace('text-align: right;', 'text-align: center')` solve the issue?

Comment: No, in fact it won't even replace the `<tr style="text-align: right;">` for whatever reason. Hmm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169264/discussion-between-richard-golz-and-bubble-bubble-bubble-gut).

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as correct due to the "modifying the string you get after using df.to_html"

Comment: I Came here while searching for formatting a multi-level column. formatters={'Name': lambda x: '<b>' + x + '</b>'}. Here it is referring to the main column x. How can i refer to a sub-column within the same column for formatting.

Comment: You forget to add `escape=False`, otherwise the HTML tag will get escaped. (`<` becomes `&lt;`)

Answer (score 8):

After some research and the help of [Bubble Bubble Bubble Gut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6805091/bubble-bubble-bubble-gut), this can be easily done by replacing all of the `<tr>` tags with `<tr align="center">` via:

```
html2 = html.replace('<tr>', '<tr align="center">')
print(html2)
```

Comment: Or like this with CSS for example for both TD and TH tags  `html = str(df_group[:5].to_html()).replace('<td>', '<td style="text-align: left">').replace('<th>', '<th style="text-align: left">')`

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem with make a little change in CSS and python code. Here's my python code :

```
dft.to_html(classes=["table-bordered", "table-striped", "table-hover", "isi"]
```

I make "isi" class and write it in CSS like this :

```
.isi {
text-align:center; }
```

Here's the result
[Values Centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FykVV.png)

Comment: For those not familiar with CSS, the code should be complete. The code sample gives 'invalid syntax' error on the definition of "isi"

Answer (score 1):

if you want the entire table to be centred just use the **justify** parameter:

```
 df.to_html(justify="center")
```

Comment: The `justify=` parameter justifies *column labels* (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)).

Comment: This solution worked for me with `**justify="left"**`. Simple and Easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the `Styler` object instead of the `to_html()` parameters. This way you can separate the styling from the rendering.

```py
# create test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"what": ["a", "b", "c", "d"], "howmuch": [55, 60, 101, 78]})

# create a Styler
df_styled = df.style.set_properties(
    **{"text-align": "center", "font-weight": "bold"}
).hide(axis="index")

# export html with style
df_styled.to_html("myFile.html")
```

Comment: how can you align the entire dataframe table container on an html page?

Comment: @pdangelo4 check out the `pandas.io.formats.style.Styler` class. There is certianly a way to add custom CSS.