# Pandas: hyper link to one of the columns in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Flask Python. So please accept my apology if my problem seems to be trivial or stupid. I am displaying a dataframe in the form of table on html page. I want to data one column into existing dataframe with name 'link' (that contains clickable link) so that when user clicks on the column value, it goes to some page. In short I want something like that:
[image]

I borrowed the idea from one of the existing threads [How to create a table with clickable hyperlink in pandas & Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263946/how-to-create-a-table-with-clickable-hyperlink-in-pandas-jupyter-notebook). However, it produces the actual output like this:

[image: Actual output]

Here is part of my code:

```
def make_clickable(val1='welcome.html',val2='Click here'):
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(val1,val2)

df['Link']= df.style.format(make_clickable)
```

Could anyone point me where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 3):

This work fine with ***Jupyter Notebook***

code:

```
import pandas as pd ; import numpy as np
data = [dict(name='Google', url='http://www.google.com'),
        dict(name='Stackoverflow', url='http://stackoverflow.com')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def make_clickable(val):
    # target _blank to open new window
    return '<a target="_blank" href="{}">{}</a>'.format(val,val)

df.style.format({'url': make_clickable})
```

proof:

[image]

Comment: Not using f strings ? (:

Comment: @Datanovice I think that can be work as well , but when i test my environment with Jupyter pandas style work just fine :-)

Comment: @WeNYoBen I am using PyCharm CE IDE. Do you think its IDE issue or "welcome.html" is located locally?

Comment: @user2293224 I think that is ide problem