# Pandas set style for Timedelta columns

Tags: pandas, database, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter notebook in which I'm displaying a dataframe that I would like to:

- Hide the index
- Display a url as a clickable link
- Display a Timedelta column to the nearest day

By default the timedelta display was working, however when I try to add styling for the other two, the display for the timedelta changes to include hours/minutes/seconds.

I assume I need to specify the format for the timedelta, but I can't seem to figure out the correct way to do so. If it were a decimal field, I know I could do something like `"column":"{:.2f}"` but that doesn't work with timedeltas.

Example Time!

```
import pandas
data = {
"count": [],
"api_id": [],
"Timedeltas": []
}
for i in range(10):
    data["count"].append(i)
    data["api_id"].append(f"/some_url/{i}")
    data["Timedeltas"].append(pandas.Timedelta(days=i))

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
df
```

By default the Timedelta column looks like I want
[image: Default Dataframe Display]

But if I apply formatting to get the other two pieces, I lose the timedelta formatting

```
def make_hyperlink(val):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56615369/2498161
    # target _blank to open new window
    return f'<a target="_blank" href="{val}">&#128279;</a>'

df.style.format(formatter={'api_id': make_hyperlink}).hide_index()
```

[image: Index removed, hyperlinks added, but timedelta incorrect format]

So my question is how do I format the timedelta, or stop the other changes from altering it's display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite an easy fix, just add a formatter for the `Timedelta` column also:

```py
df.style.format(formatter={
    'api_id': make_hyperlink,
    'Timedeltas': lambda v: f"{v.round('d').days} days",
}).hide()
```