# How to convert pandas dataframe index as a clickable link?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
        heading1  heading2
 issue1 data        data
 issue2 data        data
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZmpI.png)

And I am converting this to excel using `df.to_excel` function.
Now I want to convert the index to clickable hyperlinks.
For example - If i click Issue1, it should take me to `www.issue1.com`. I know how to convert pandas dataframe column to hyperlink, but not sure if I can make the indices clickable. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263946/how-to-create-a-table-with-clickable-hyperlink-in-pandas-jupyter-notebook

hope this helps

Comment: The thread in the above link tells how to make column  values as hyperlink but I want the index values as hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.set_index` along with `pandas.DataFrame.index`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        MUL1=["Data", "Data"],
        MUL2=["Data", "Data"],
    ),
    index=["Issue1", "Issue2"],
)

df = df.set_index("www." + df.index + ".com")
print(df)
```

edit: OP commented:

> This just changes the index from 'issue1' to 'www.issue1.com' but does not make it clickable. (=HYPERLINK) – Aditya Garg

My response is that the clickabilty of the link depends on what program you are displaying the link in. I use Pycharm, which is able to detect URLs in console output and makes them clickable by default:
[image]

That being said it may not be clickable when running the script in other programs like cmd.exe for example. Making it into an [html](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) or [markdown style](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#links) link is not going to change this for things like cmd.  However, if you're going to display this DataFrame in something that does support a particular link formatting method, then you can try some of the following examples:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        MUL1=["Data", "Data"],
        MUL2=["Data", "Data"],
    ),
    index=["Issue1", "Issue2"],

)
index = df.index

# Basic link example
df = df.set_index('www.' + index + '.com/')
print(df)

# Markdown Link Example
df = df.set_index("[" + index + "](www." + index + ".com)")
print(df)

# angle bracket format example
df = df.set_index("<www." + index + ".com>")
print(df)

# html link example
df = df.set_index('<a href="www.' + index + '.com">' + index + '</a>')
print(df)
```

Comment: This just changes the index from 'issue1' to 'www.issue1.com' but does not make it clickable.
(=HYPERLINK)

Comment: Edited my answer with a response to your comment Aditya Garg