# Pandas make a column clickable and sort

Tags: python, pandas, clickable

I followed this post [How to create a table with clickable hyperlink in pandas & Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263946/how-to-create-a-table-with-clickable-hyperlink-in-pandas-jupyter-notebook) to create a clickable link in a dataframe. However, it seems any time I sort the dataframe, the hyper links go away.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['http://google.com', 'http://duckduckgo.com'], columns=["a"])

def make_clickable(val):
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(val,val)

df.style.format(make_clickable)
```

This will display unclickable links:

```
df.sort_values(by="a")
```

Comment: `df.style.format(make_clickable)` does output the correct (clickable) links on my notebook. Maybe you've missed capturing the output? `df = df.style.format(make_clickable)`?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used styling before so I might be wrong. According to what I can find in the [Styling documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) styles are not meant for defining a default HTML representation of a DataFrame. The expected way to work with styles is to call `DataFrame.style.format()` every time you need the given formatting options to be applied, in your case that would be:

```py
df.sort_values(by='a').style.format({'a': make_clickable})
```

From your question I guess you would like to force a given column to always display in a given way when you simply have a DataFrame as the last line of a cell. Here are two solutions that you may try.

#### Solution 1

We can define a shortcut for this which could especially be handy if we need to have a more complex formatting strategy:

```py
def clickable_links(df):
    return df.style.format({'a': make_clickable})
```

Then simply:

```py
clickable_links(df.sort_values(by='a'))
```

#### Solution 2

Another viable solution (just for fun) would be automatically have all links (columns with name `'a'`) clickable for all DataFrames:

```py
def format_all_html_repr(format_options):
    pd.DataFrame._repr_html_ = lambda self: self.style.format(format_options).render()

format_all_html_repr({'a': make_clickable})

df = pd.DataFrame(['http://google.com', 'http://duckduckgo.com'], columns=['a'])
```

Then we don't need to be as explicit as we were in solution 1:

```py
df.sort_values(by='a')
```

The drawback of this second solution is that every DataFrame will now format `a` columns as links in their HTML output.

#### Details on solution 2

The idea of this solution is to modify how HTML is rendered by default. In your notebook, everytime a cell ends with a DataFrame `df` it automatically calls `df._repr_html_`. We can use that to modify the default behaviour. One way is to simply bind the function `pandas.DataFrame._repr_html_` to the function we like.

You can't really define this behaviour for a single DataFrame by binding the method `df._repr_html_` directly for a given instance because this modification wouldn't be passed to descendent DataFrames. In other words `df._repr_html` would be different from `df.sort_values(by='a')._repr_html` because `df` and `df.sort_values(by='a')` are two distinct instances of DataFrame. They don't share their methods.

Maybe a middle ground could be found by copying the method when slicing/sorting/or applying any transformation to `df`, but that would probably be a bit more complex to write.