# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 6), indices imply (4, 6) error when merging two df in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `dataframe` as below:

```
      Background    Skin            Body               Face          Head
value   Beige     Light Gray   TribalNecklace        Beard          Bowl Cut
value   Blue      Normal        BowTie Pink         Blushing        Durag Red.
```

and

```
          Link
0 https://example.com
1 httpsl//example2.com
```

when joing two using below code:

```
df5 = pd.concat([df1, linkdf], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
df5
```

gives an error:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 6), indices imply (4, 6)

How do I join two `dataframe` without getting that error? Thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: What is the first column with `value`? The index?

Comment: its index cause i change from column to row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code from:

```
df5 = pd.concat([df1, linkdf], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

To

```
df5 = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(), linkdf], axis=1)
```

Gives you:

```
   index Background        Skin  ...      Face        Head                  Link
0  value      Beige  Light Gray  ...     Beard    Bowl Cut   https://example.com
1  value       Blue      Normal  ...  Blushing  Durag Red.  httpsl//example2.com
```

Comment: one more question is there a way to make the link clickable

Comment: perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263946/how-to-create-a-table-with-clickable-hyperlink-in-pandas-jupyter-notebook) will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try with `assign`:

```
df5 = df1.assign(links=linkdf.values)
```

```
>>> df5
      Background        Skin            Body      Face        Head                 links
value      Beige  Light Gray  TribalNecklace     Beard    Bowl Cut   https://example.com
value       Blue      Normal     BowTie Pink  Blushing  Durag Red.  httpsl//example2.com
```