# How can I make the links in the URL column clickable

Tags: python, dataframe, url

It would be important that not the entire URL is displayed, but perhaps only "To the article" is displayed, so that the URL behind "To the article" is deposited?

```
googlenews = GoogleNews() 
googlenews.set_encode('utf_8') 

for ort in orte: 
    googlenews.clear() 
    googlenews.get_news(ort) 
    table_new = [] 
    
    for row in googlenews.results(): 
        table_new.append({ 
            'City': ort, 
            'Title': row['title'], 
            'Date': row['date']}) 
    
        df = pd.DataFrame(table_new) 
        
    nachrichten.append(df)

dfges = pd.concat(nachrichten, axis='index')
print(dfges)
´´´
```

Comment: try to add `https://` prefix to url

Comment: How do you mean it?

Comment: For example, create func
`def make_clickable(val):
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(val,val)`
and then apply this function to url column

Comment: Thanks, but how can I implement this to the code above? I dont know how to apple it to the url column

Comment: [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263946/how-to-create-a-table-with-clickable-hyperlink-in-pandas-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Thanks, but I get errors ... Could you please edit it in my code? It is probably due to the indentations and I dont know how to solve it

Comment: did it check your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your raw URLs are not valid. To turn them into valid Google News URLs you want to add `row['link'].replace('/./article', '/article')` and add the `https://` prefix. Options to obtain the real link, have been discussed [here.](https://github.com/Iceloof/GoogleNews/issues/71).

This will turn:

```
news.google.com/./articles/CBMigQFodHRwczovL3d3dy5lc3BuLmNvbS9zb2NjZXIvZ2VybWFuLWJ1bmRlc2xpZ2Evc3RvcnkvNDYzNDMxOC91bmNvbWZvcnRhYmxlLWZyZWlidXJnLWFwcGVhbC1hZnRlci1iYXllcm4tbXVuaWNoLXN1YnN0aXR1dGlvbi1taXgtdXDSAY4BaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZXNwbi5jb20vc29jY2VyL2dlcm1hbi1idW5kZXNsaWdhL3N0b3J5LzQ2MzQzMTgvdW5jb21mb3J0YWJsZS1mcmVpYnVyZy1hcHBlYWwtYWZ0ZXItYmF5ZXJuLW11bmljaC1zdWJzdGl0dXRpb24tbWl4LXVwP3BsYXRmb3JtPWFtcA?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
```

into:

```
https://news.google.com/articles/CBMigQFodHRwczovL3d3dy5lc3BuLmNvbS9zb2NjZXIvZ2VybWFuLWJ1bmRlc2xpZ2Evc3RvcnkvNDYzNDMxOC91bmNvbWZvcnRhYmxlLWZyZWlidXJnLWFwcGVhbC1hZnRlci1iYXllcm4tbXVuaWNoLXN1YnN0aXR1dGlvbi1taXgtdXDSAY4BaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZXNwbi5jb20vc29jY2VyL2dlcm1hbi1idW5kZXNsaWdhL3N0b3J5LzQ2MzQzMTgvdW5jb21mb3J0YWJsZS1mcmVpYnVyZy1hcHBlYWwtYWZ0ZXItYmF5ZXJuLW11bmljaC1zdWJzdGl0dXRpb24tbWl4LXVwP3BsYXRmb3JtPWFtcA?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
```

To make URLs clickable, you can add the following code, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263946/how-to-create-a-table-with-clickable-hyperlink-in-pandas-jupyter-notebook):

```
def make_clickable(val):
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(val,'To the article')

dfges.style.format({'URL': make_clickable})
```

**Full code:**

```
import pandas as pd 
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews 
    
googlenews = GoogleNews() 
googlenews.set_encode('utf_8') 
googlenews.set_lang('en') 
googlenews.set_period('7d')
    
orte = ["Munich"] 
nachrichten = []
    
for ort in orte: 
    googlenews.clear() 
    googlenews.get_news(ort) 
    table_new = [] 
    
    for row in googlenews.results(): 
        table_new.append({ 
            'City': ort, 
            'Title': row['title'], 
            'Date': row['date'], 
            'URL': f"https://{row['link'].replace('/./article', '/article')}",
            'Source': row['site'], }) 
    
        df = pd.DataFrame(table_new) 
        
    nachrichten.append(df)

dfges = pd.concat(nachrichten, axis='index')
dfges.drop_duplicates(subset=['Title'], keep='last', inplace=True)
print(dfges)

def make_clickable(val):
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(val,'To the article')

dfges.style.format({'URL': make_clickable})
```

**Output:**

Open link in a new tab, which leads to a page redirecting to the original article.

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tested the code and the links are clickable but when I tried one of them I got `400. That’s an error.`. Are those links valid?

Comment: @YasserKhalil Try to do a right click and open link in a new tab. Otherwise the redirect won't happen. Don't know why Google doesn't allow them straight away.

Comment: Thanks but the same problem `The server cannot process the request because it is malformed`

Comment: Could you share the title of the article or the URL please? Don't get  response.

Comment: It is my bad. I just have seen the dataframe `print(dfges)` and didn't notice the last dataframe `dfges.style.format({'URL': make_clickable})`. Now I can see the clickable working links

Comment: unfortunately it does not work for me..

Comment: @David_Python Could you please elaborate? It's only for formatting, won't be part of a csv. Is this, what you mean?

Comment: I am sending dfges with Mail and in the Mail I see the whole URL which also not clickable bro ...

Comment: @David_Python Yes, it's because it's only a formatter for displaying purporse. What is the type of attachment? You could try to write an `apply()` function, that does the conversion, but it will still not work for csv.

Comment: Thank a lot It works now :) Can you please check this question? Probably you know what to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71795148/python-html-table-should-be-striped