# Python: HTML table should be striped

Tags: python, html, dataframe

Would it be possible to have the table the same size and shape but with one row in white and the other in light gray? Thus, the table should be striped to the end, where just one row is white and the other gray.

```
html = """\
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    {0}
    </body>
    </html>
    """.format(dfges.to_html(index=False, escape=False))
    msg.set_content(html, 'html')

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, smtp_port) as server:
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(from_mail, from_password)
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()
send_email(smtp_server, smtp_port, from_mail, from_password, to_mail)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can use the CSS property [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child). An alternative approach would be to use [Table Formatters.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html)

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

dfges = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[3,4]],columns=['foo', 'bar'])

html = f"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
tr:nth-child(even) {{
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}}
</style>
</head>
<body>
{dfges.to_html(index=False, escape=False)}
</body>
</html>"""

display(HTML(html))
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

**Full code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib

dfges = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame()], axis='index')

from email.message import EmailMessage
from_mail = 'Example@example.com'

from_password = '.....'

to_mail = ['Example@example.com']
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtp_port = 465

def send_email(smtp_server, smtp_port, from_mail, from_password, to_mail):
  '''
  Send results via mail
  '''

  msg = EmailMessage()
  msg['Subject'] = 'Subject'
  msg['From'] = from_mail
  msg['To'] = ', '.join(to_mail)

  html = f"""
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
  <style>
  tr:nth-child(even) {{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  {dfges.to_html(index=False, escape=False)}
  </body>
  </html>"""
  msg.set_content(html, 'html')

  with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, smtp_port) as server:
      server.ehlo()
      server.login(from_mail, from_password)
      server.send_message(msg)
      server.quit()
send_email(smtp_server, smtp_port, from_mail, from_password, to_mail)
```

Comment: Thanks, can you edit in the code? I dont know where to put it in..

Comment: @David_Python Just use it as a replacement for the the part, where you create the `html` string. Should match now pretty much, what you had.

Comment: It doesn't work because in my code msg.set is causing problems.

Comment: @David_Python What is the error? I can not verify.

Comment: dfges = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4]], columns=['foo', 'bar'])
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: You don't need that part, as you got a dfges already, created with the `concat` prompt.

Comment: Could you probably edit it fully in the code? Because I dont get it, which part should be removed

Comment: When I run the code, I only get in the mail one single cell thats it.. I guess there is a problem

Comment: It can not be. Did you try to print the html being generated and open visualize it with a browser? Do you only have on article maybe?