# Add hyperlinks to pandas Styler table depending on index and column of each cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like

|  | foo | bar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| England | 3.0 | 4.0 |
| France | 5.0 | 6.0 |

and I want to save it to an html file using `Styler.to_html()` with clickable links on each cell number. Each hyperlink should be dependant on its corresponding index and column. For example clicking `1.0` should open a URL like `http://example.com/foo/Germany.html`.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263946/how-to-create-a-table-with-clickable-hyperlink-in-pandas-jupyter-notebook) but it appears like using `Styler.format` does not allow me to access the corresponding index and column of the cell to be formatted so it's not possible to embed those into the hyperlink.

How can something like this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styler.format method takes a cell value and can restructure it, including formatting it into a hyperlink.

Suppose your cell value was "w;v", then `"<a x={0}>{1}".format(cell_value.split(";"))` would return `"<a x=w>v"`.

The trick in your case is pre-preparing the dataframe with the data in a necessary format before it is passed to Styler such that the styler element -by- element style formatting method can be applied as above.

Comment: This is a good answer. Could it somehow be combined with `Styler.background_gradient` so that the numbers/hyperlinks can also have a value-dependant background color?

Comment: yes because background gradient has a gmap or gradient map argument that allows you specify the color grdient values independent of the dataframe contents